# Android Studio: The application installed from Run 'app' and application installed from build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk are different

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I am still new to android studio application and here is the problem I have faced:

When I'm running the application from Run 'app' in the android studio, all of the application functions work and I am able to run the rating bar and location map in my application.

However, when trying to install it via the app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk, all of the application functions work except the rating bar and location map in my application. The app crashes after I click on the button that intent these functions. Why does it not working?

---

[Working] Running from Run 'app' in android studio:

The screenshot of rating and locate button:

[image: Screenshot displaying both rating and locate button]

The screenshot of working rating function:

[image: Screenshot displaying working rating funciton]

The screenshot of working locate function:

[image: Screenshot displaying working locate funciton]

---

[Not Working] Running from app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk:

The screenshot of rating and locate button:

[image: Screenshot displaying both rating and locate button]

The screenshot of app crashes after a click on either the rating or locate button:

[image: Screenshot app crashes]

What I have tried:

I have already clean the project/rebuild the project/or even manually delete the build folder to rebuild the project to generate new APK.

I have also updated the dependencies to the newest version.

Yet, not working.

I expect all the functions in the application will run smoothly when trying to install the application from app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk, but it crashes.

Here is the debug logcat when I clicked on the rate button:

```
2019-08-13 18:32:17.760 13713-13713/? I/e.nad.whattoea: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-08-13 18:32:17.823 13713-13713/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
2019-08-13 18:32:17.822 13713-13713/? W/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:1239971): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=7827 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c80,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
2019-08-13 18:32:17.855 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/VivoTheme: load old package name start
2019-08-13 18:32:17.865 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/e.nad.whattoea: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-08-13 18:32:18.278 13713-13748/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2019-08-13 18:32:18.301 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
2019-08-13 18:32:18.302 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2019-08-13 18:32:18.302 13713-13750/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2019-08-13 18:32:18.309 13713-13750/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
2019-08-13 18:32:18.309 13713-13750/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
2019-08-13 18:32:18.314 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/NightModeController: learncode.nad.whattoeat = true
2019-08-13 18:32:18.314 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/NightModeController: disable nightmode package:learncode.nad.whattoeat
2019-08-13 18:32:18.353 13713-13747/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 16250
2019-08-13 18:32:18.353 13713-13747/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2019-08-13 18:32:18.353 13713-13747/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app learncode.nad.whattoeat
2019-08-13 18:32:18.353 13713-13747/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2019-08-13 18:32:18.366 13713-13747/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(177:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:168;Function:ASN1_get_object
2019-08-13 18:32:18.374 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/FtBuild: getRomVersion mRomVer=9.0
2019-08-13 18:32:18.384 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/e.nad.whattoea: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2019-08-13 18:32:18.385 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/e.nad.whattoea: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
2019-08-13 18:32:18.385 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/e.nad.whattoea: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
2019-08-13 18:32:18.385 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/e.nad.whattoea: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
2019-08-13 18:32:18.385 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/e.nad.whattoea: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
2019-08-13 18:32:18.411 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
2019-08-13 18:32:18.462 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/VivoPhoneWindow: DEBUG_ALIENSCREEN:getRotation mRotation=0
2019-08-13 18:32:18.463 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/PhoneWindow: initSystemUIColor
2019-08-13 18:32:18.492 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/e.nad.whattoea: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-08-13 18:32:18.494 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/e.nad.whattoea: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-08-13 18:32:18.634 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/e.nad.whattoea: Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic; (light greylist, linking)
2019-08-13 18:32:18.709 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-08-13 18:32:18.709 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/SurfaceFactory: [static] sSurfaceFactory = com.mediatek.view.impl.SurfaceFactoryImpl@2e418c9
2019-08-13 18:32:18.716 13713-13747/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2019-08-13 18:32:18.723 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
2019-08-13 18:32:18.729 13713-13747/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-2282275983064218132}]
2019-08-13 18:32:18.750 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/CatcherGestureDetector: DecorView onAttached
2019-08-13 18:32:18.751 13713-13758/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-08-13 18:32:18.756 13713-13758/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
2019-08-13 18:32:18.758 13713-13758/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/System.out: e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
2019-08-13 18:32:18.758 13713-13758/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/Linux: [Posix_connect Debug]Process learncode.nad.whattoeat :443 
2019-08-13 18:32:18.802 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7dfb784000)
2019-08-13 18:32:18.811 13713-13757/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-08-13 18:32:18.811 13713-13757/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-08-13 18:32:18.811 13713-13757/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-08-13 18:32:18.811 13713-13757/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2019-08-13 18:32:18.811 13713-13757/learncode.nad.whattoeat E/OpenGLRenderer: Device claims wide gamut support, cannot find matching config, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2019-08-13 18:32:18.817 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2019-08-13 18:32:18.820 13713-13757/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7dfb784000,api=1)
2019-08-13 18:32:18.821 13713-13757/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2019-08-13 18:32:18.848 13713-13750/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(177:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:168;Function:ASN1_get_object
2019-08-13 18:32:18.969 13713-13757/learncode.nad.whattoeat E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2019-08-13 18:32:19.011 13713-13747/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/FA: Connected to remote service
2019-08-13 18:32:19.267 13713-13758/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(177:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:168;Function:ASN1_get_object
2019-08-13 18:32:19.268 13713-13758/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(177:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:168;Function:ASN1_get_object
2019-08-13 18:32:20.817 13713-13784/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-08-13 18:32:20.834 13713-13784/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-08-13 18:32:20.848 13713-13784/learncode.nad.whattoeat I/chatty: uid=10336(learncode.nad.whattoeat) glide-disk-cach identical 1 line
2019-08-13 18:32:20.863 13713-13784/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-08-13 18:32:20.871 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/Glide: Load failed for  with size [453x390]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
2019-08-13 18:32:20.871 13713-13713/learncode.nad.whattoeat W/Glide: Load failed for  with size [453x390]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
2019-08-13 18:32:20.876 13713-13784/learncode.nad.whattoeat D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1
```

The logcat after filter to error:

```
2019-08-13 18:36:18.694 13899-13899/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
2019-08-13 18:36:18.708 13899-13914/? E/e.nad.whattoea: Unable to peek into adb socket due to error. Closing socket.: Connection reset by peer
2019-08-13 18:36:19.731 13899-13950/learncode.nad.whattoeat E/OpenGLRenderer: Device claims wide gamut support, cannot find matching config, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2019-08-13 18:36:19.744 13899-13899/learncode.nad.whattoeat E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2019-08-13 18:36:19.889 13899-13950/learncode.nad.whattoeat E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
```

Comment: post crash logs

Comment: What is the exception that is causing your app to crash ?

Comment: I have included the log @OmInfowaveDevelopers

Comment: In your logs, there is nowhere RuntimeException. Post the part of logcat that contains RuntimeException logs. Try this, as soon as the app crashes, search for RuntimeException in logcat then upload that part.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is a permission issue and some of the cell phones don't give the correct/actual logs. You have missed any permission which has to be mention in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: This could be written as a comment I guess.

Comment: @AhmadMaleki Many new comers don't notice comments. Even I when was new to stackoverflow, didn't noticed what the comments said. I only looked at the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error about 'persist.vendor.sys.activitylog', and wasted the better part of an hour on it.

I can confirm that it is phone-dependent.

The error appears to be coming from the initial launching of the app. before anything happens in my (very simple) code.  Something like this from a Nokia 1 running Android 9:

```
I/ActivityManager: Start proc <proc-id>:org.goldang.appdope.dbg/u0a472 for activity org.mydom.myapp.dbg/org.mydom.myapp.MainActivity
I/ang.myapp.db: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
I/ADB_SERVICES: service_to_fd shell:stat -c %u /proc/20716 | xargs -n 1 pm list packages --uid
W/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:23144): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=7302 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c216,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
I/ang.myapp.db: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall and run again. Works for me.